# Usage of free() function

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose i have a linked list node with a head pointer and i passed head to some other function
like test(node *np)

what happens if i free np inside this function test with head might or might not be pointing to the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C standard using `free` with improper pointer is undefined behavior:

> **7.22.3.3 The `free` function**
>
> ....
>
> The **`free`** function causes the space pointed to by **`ptr`** to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If **`ptr`** is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to **`free`** or **`realloc`**, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: I created the head by (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)) where node is a typedef of the struct linkedlistnode.So what you are saying is inorder to delete the node i can do it by only free(head) but not by free(np) even though np and head point to the same node,isnt it?

Comment: @sarat No, if `np == head` then `free(np)` and `free(head)` are the same.